# Gradle not building

Tags: android-studio, gradle, windows-10

The following error occurs and none of my android projects sync with gradle. This occurred spontaneously when I opened android studio. My JAVA_HOME user variable is set to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin'. Also, JDK location in android studio wont change from F:\Softwares\Android\jre to anything because it changes back when I try to change it.

```
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected. 
Java home is differnt.
Expecting: 'F:\Softwares\Android\jre' but was: 'C:\Program
Files\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_144'. Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sdk and ndk location to somewhere else, so that the warnings for space in paths donot occur. Then I could change the JDK location inside android studio to 'C:\ProgramFiles\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_144'. This fixed the gradle problem.